# Dividing PowerBuilder Bar Chart by Month

Tags: graph, powerbuilder

I have a bar chart.  Loading it up with expenditures that have a datetime is not hard, but I would like to collate this data by month.

I think I already read that the autoscale "rounding" feature wont work for this, and I think I need to create Major Divisions.  However, this is greyed out.  (Autoscale is also greyed out oddly)

If I can't find a better solution, I might just have to make a view for JUST this graph, which is kind of lame.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Drennen

Answer (score 0):

Well, you probably already solved this but I'll answer it for the next person.

I personally would simply create another column, it can be a dummy column from the database, or one on the client end of dataobject that grabs the "Month" portion of the data. I've done reports like this before, and it kind of stinks if you don't know your range as you don't know how many different buckets there will be when designing the report.

Sometimes I make a stored procedure and flatten the data out on the back-end but a simpler but less flexible way is to grab the month portion of the data like:

```
select sum(col1), max(col2), to_char(expenditure_date, 'MONTH') as exp_month
from your_table
where you are happy
group by to_char(expenditure_date, 'MONTH)

or

select col1, col2, mid(to_char(exp_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')1,2) as month_mm
from your_table
where everyone is happy

// then group on the month dummy col and you can do collating/summing on the client report as well.
```